# Android Emulator Required Files

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to share one of my android emulators and am trying to figure out what is needed.

I have copied my `c:\users\me\appdata\local\android\sdk` folder with the exception of the platforms folder which doesn't appear to be needed. Along with my `.avd` folder and the corresponding `.ini`. Whilst this is working it's very big and I would like to see if I can slim it down.

I get the impression the system-images folder should only be required to create a new virtual machine, but for some reason if I try and start my `avd` without the required system-image I get an error. Why is the system image required?

What are the files within my `.avd`;

- `userdata.img`
- `userdata-qemu.img`
- `userdata-qemu.img.qcow2`

Are there other folders from the sdk folder I can drop?

In several instances my virtual machine has seemed to reset (i.e. all config and installed apps have vanished). Are there any obvious events that could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the whole `*.avd` folder and **modify the configuration files** properly. E.g. you have an avd named **Pixel_2_API_26**, which is **by default** under directory `~/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_26.avd` on **Mac machines**. So, you need to copy this `Pixel_2_API_26.avd` folder completely and put it under the corresponding location on your other machines.

Then either copy or create a file with the same file name, i.e. `Pixel_2_API_26` but with extension of `.ini` and put it under the same location, i.e. `~/.android/avd/`, modify the content as below:

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
path=~/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_26.avd
path.rel=avd/Pixel_2_API_26.avd
target=android-26
```

Then fix all the wrong paths inside all the configuration files, e.g.

- `Pixel_2_API_26.avd/config.ini`
- `Pixel_2_API_26.avd/hardware-qemu.ini`

Comment: Hi shizhen. I have already been able to copy over a number of virtual machines (and didn't need to make any changes to the config files- which is a little odd). The question is more around what is actually needed and why. I want to distribute my VM with the minimal package size (at the moment it's about 7.5gb; the avd folder is 5gb and the system-image is 2.5gb)

Comment: Weird to hear that the emulator works well without any modifications, Are you using the same paths for other machines? But if you distribute your settings as a  complete VM, then surely it will work.

Comment: The paths are different, but I think the path.rel is being used which obviously is the same.